# Using Storage::makeDirectory() not creating a folder in laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to save a folder to the storage folder, but it isn't creating the folder.
What happens is that, I save the folder name in a form and what I want to happen is that if that folder doesn't exist then create it.

Here is my code

```
public function createFolder()
{
    $base = storage_path("app/folder/".request('folder'));
    if(!file_exists($base))
    {
        Storage::makeDirectory($base);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do some think like this

```
$path="folder/".request()->folder;

$folderExist= Storage::exists($path);

if(!$folderExist){
    
    Storage::makeDirectory($path);
}
```

Comment: That worked. Could you explain why what I did didn't work

Comment: @Aurilie i think path generated from storage_path not suite for creating directory may be due to slashes